# Huge Lists - how to make sure they still work beyond the 5k threshold

Tags: list, spservices

I am building a site at the moment with two lists (one for emails, one for documents) which have the potential to be massive (1.2 million entries) but it still needs to function and be searchable using spservices jquery library.

I have gotten this to work previously by setting indexes and only searching on one column within the list.

Is there anything else that I need to consider?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just make sure that when you querying those lists use Row limit and pagination and everything will work fine

Comment: Since he is querying on the indexed column, I don't think he will require  Row limit and pagination.

Comment: If you are working with a large dataset/list, SharePoint Enterprise Search (SP2010, I don't know how its called in SP2013) could be an option, as you can create Managed Properties for columns you are using for filtering, and query data efficiently.